# trim custom field text value and show (...)

Tags: custom-field, meta-value

I am using this code here:

```
<?php
$trim_length = 25;  //desired length of text to display
$custom_field = 'my-custom-field-name';
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true);
if ($value) {
 echo rtrim(substr($value,0,$trim_length));
}
?>
```

It works - but I would like to have a "(...)" at the end of the trimmed text. And *only* if the value really was trimmed.

I used `if ($value) {
     echo rtrim(substr($value,0,$trim_length)) . '(...)';
    }
    ?>`
But this makes the "(...)" at the end of every text from custom field..

Thank you!

AD

Comment: [Don’t use `strlen()` or `substr()`](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

building on keatch's answer you only need to trim if its longer the 25 chars so:

```
$trim_length = 25;  //desired length of text to display
$custom_field = 'my-custom-field-name';
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true);
if ($value) {
    if (strlen($value) > $trim_length)
        $value = rtrim(substr($value,0,$trim_length)) .'(...)';
 echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

You must check if the string was trimmed. If it is, is length is `$trim_length`
So, you must add the '(...)' at the end

```
<?php
$trim_length = 25;  //desired length of text to display
$custom_field = 'my-custom-field-name';
$value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true);
if ($value) {
 $trimmed_value= rtrim(substr($value,0,$trim_length));
 if (strlen($trimmed_value) >= $trim_length)
    $trimmed_value .= " (...)";
 echo $trimmed_value;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Wordpress 3.3 there is a built-in function for this : [wp_trim_words()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) which accepts as arguments the number of words and the chain the add if trimmed.

So you could do something like :

```
 <?php
  $trim_length = 25;  //desired length of text to display
  $value_more = '(...)'; // what to add at the end of the trimmed text
  $custom_field = 'my-custom-field-name';
  $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field, true);
   if ($value) {
      echo wp_trim_words( $value, $trim_length, $value_more);
   }
   ?>
```